# github transferring ownership to an organization removes the repo permissions

Tags: github

I am a member of organization 'B' with permissions to create a repository.I have transferred a repository from organization 'A' to 'B'.But I have lost admin access to the repo.why do the permissions not stay intact upon transferring the ownership.?

Answer (score 1):

Now the new owner(and admin) of "your" repository is the organization to which your repository was transferred. As you aren't the owner of your repository, you can't edit it.